# How to deal with VNC login issues and error

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, vnc, raspberry-pi-os

I'm doing a project with a Pi 4B, the official touchscreen and the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS. I would like to connect to the Pi via VNC (RealVNC Viewer on Windows 10) at a higher resolution for development work.

I've enabled VNC in `raspi-config`, and it works perfectly when I use just the IP as the client address - the only issue is that it's fixed to the resolution of the touchscreen.

When I create another VNC server with `vncserver -randr=1920x1080`, I can connect to it on `[IP address]:1`. But I've found two issues (so far):

- I get this error when I log in:

  ```
  GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication
  agent already exists for the given subject
  ```
- The mouse cursor isn't correct - it's just an 'X' and isn't context sensitive.

The usual solution for the first issue (Untick "LXPolKit..." in Desktop Session Settings) doesn't apply here - that option isn't there. I have no idea how to fix the other issue.

Any idea how I sort these things out? I don't understand why the two VNC servers are behaving differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the black X issue with (I set my Pi's up with a script that is stateful and persistent through reboots)

```
# Fix the Black X problem
sudo cp /etc/vnc/xstartup /etc/vnc/xstartup.custom 
sudo sed -i 's/xsetroot -solid grey/xsetroot -solid grey -cursor\_name left_ptr/g' /etc/vnc/xstartup.custom
```